# Django 2.1: Template structure

Tags: django, django-2.1

I am having trouble with Django routing to find templates located at the app-level. That is, templates at the app-level directory are not rendered unless I put them in the root project-level directory. But the problem with this architecture for me is that, if I have two or more apps all having a file named `home.html` how do I resolve that from the templates folder at the project-level so that they won't be confliction.

**Error message**

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DEV\PYTHON\DEVELOPMENT\WILLIAM-VINCENT-PROJECT\django-begin\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
```

I was expecting Django to search the `/templates/posts` and `/templates/pages` folders to fetch the files. It is rather trying to fetch the files directly from the `templates` folder. If I were to put the HTML files directly into the `/templates/` folder then that would conflicts since apps have similar file names

**Project directory structure**

```
|__my-project
|__manage.py
|__pages
|__posts
|__templates
   |__pages
   |  |__home.html
   |  |__about.html
   |__posts
      |__home.html
      |__about.html
```

I want each app to have its own `home.html` and `about.html`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your templates need to be saved in the following way:

`ProjectName/AppName/Templates/AppName/Template.html`

So if your project was called `DjangoProject` and your app was called `DjangoApp` it would be: `DjangoProject/DjangoApp/Templates/DjangoApp/Template.html`

This is the same for any app you start within your project.

EDIT:

Currently you have a `templates` folder within your project directory. That is wrong.

You need a `templates` folder for each app *within* that apps directory.

So `my-project/pages/templates/pages`
and `my-project/posts/templates/posts`

NOT `my-project/templates/`

Comment: I did just exactly that for the app-level directory and it didn't work for me

Comment: Please post your `settings.py` file.

Comment: @sharhan-alhassan I have updated my answer. You need to delete the `templates` folder from within the project directory and create a `templates` directory within each apps directory.